# What type of wood is this?

Tags: wood, staining

I've started my first home renovation project and I've stained this floor, after doing this I was told (by an amateur home renovator) that I'm not supposed to stain that kind of wood. Could anyone tell me what kind of wood they think it is so that I can verify?

Thanks in advance.

[image: wood floor]

[image: close up of wood floor]

Comment: Can you provide a close up?

Comment: Added a close up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the color (light; pink tinge), knots (lots), and grain (wide) I would say it's a soft wood but I don't know what type. Common soft wood flooring would be pine and fir. Soft woods can be dented with your fingernail (unlike oak, for example—a common hardwood species for flooring).

You can definitely stain pine, but that floor doesn't look stained to me. What exactly did you do?

Comment: Sorry, after rereading my OP I can see it is confusing, this was before the stain went on, I wanted you guys to see what it looked like before I stained it.

Comment: Very late to the party, but I agree on the pine or fir diagnosis. The most likely reason your friend told you not to stain the wood is that pine can turn out blotchy. To combat this, use a wood conditioner prior to applying the stain.